# How to make jQuery get PHP parameters from mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can I make jQuery get the PHP parameter from `mysql_fetch_array()`? Below is part of my code, any suggestion would be welcomed.

**PHP**

```
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($list=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            print"
<div id=\"#$list[id]\" class=\"f\">
```

**jQuery**

```
switch(id) {
case '#$list[id]':
```

(I'm trying to use Fancybox with this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844043/1575921)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use $.ajax() for this?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourphpcode.php',
  success: function(data) {
    // all your $list variables are saved in data
    // so you can work from here with your data array
  }
});
```

php:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($list = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo $list['id'];
}
```

It's most likely you get something like this back from php:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
etc.
```

with javascript you can split this with:

```
dataArray = data.split(”\n“);
```

so your final code would be:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'yourphpcode.php',
      success: function(data) {
        dataArray = data.split("\n");
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use PHP vars from within your JS Code, it's a completely different environment.
The PHP code runs on the server, the JS code in the browser.

You can however use PHP to print the content of a variable, it is possible to 'produce' the JS code in PHP.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  var myvar = '".$list[id]."';
</script>";
```

Afterwards you can use myvar in the JS code

```
switch(id) {
case myvar:
```

Comment: This will only work on initialization of your script. When you want to refresh your $list[id]'s later on in the script, this won't work.